# Tortoise SVN Show Log from root folder doesn't show all

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm new to SVN (long-time cvs user), and am using Tortoise 1.6 (not allowed to update Tortoise).

My problem is this:  performing the Show Log option from the root folder doesn't show revisions/commits that are correctly displayed when performing Show Log on individual revised/committed files from the sub-folder.

The Repo Browser option shows the same problem.

Tried the following without success:  Disabling Log Caching, un-selecting "Hide unrelated changed paths", "Stop on copy/rename", and selecting "Include merged versions"

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: With "root folder" you mean the root folder of your svn-server or your trunk?

Comment: I think I mean my trunk (I apologize for being such an SVN newbie).  My "root folder" is the top-most folder which was created by Tortoise on my local PC when I first performed "SVN Checkout".

Comment: Are your "sub-folder" (which are branches form trunk ?) reintegrated/merged back to your trunk (aka root folder). If not it is perfectly normal that you can´t see the commits from branches in trunk log.

Comment: Don't know - I didn't create/assemble the repository.  Is there a way to see a single list of all commits, from branches or not, for a checked-out trunk (perhaps since a given date), preferably using Tortoise ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe those subfolders are externals to the main folder. It doesn't matter if an external points to the same repository as the main folder itself. To view the log you'd have to checkout the working copy in which this folder will not be an external. Or do what you've been doing already, view logs from subfolders.

To find out which folders are externals right-click on main folder and then in menu go to TortoiseSVN > Properties. You will see a list of items. If one of them is `svn:externals` then that's it. Edit it, and in new window you'll see one or more items consisting of subfolder name and an URL to external repository. URL may be relative, with all kinds of "relativeness". To learn more about externals go to appropriate [TortoiseSVN doc page](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html).

Comment: "Maybe those subfolders are externals to the main folder" - how can one determine whether or not the subfolders are externals to the main ?  "checkout the working copy in which this folder will not be an external" - Seems like one might want all subfolders to not be externals (or is this not doable/advisable ?), in order to be able to get a log of all revisions/commits for a project

Comment: There are benefits in having externals, and they arguably outweigh the cost of not having an all-encompassing log.

Comment: I understand there are trade-offs, but is there a way to get an all-encompassing log which includes the commits made to externals, preferably using Tortoise ?  (My reading of the on-line SVN docs only points to the "Show Log" option.)

Comment: @7579 There is no such functionality. Sometimes someone asks for it, but it's not made yet. Maybe you could write a script that takes main log, and checks for externals, and then takes their logs too, and then merge those logs. It's imaginable...

Comment: sincere thanks for your help - i do enjoy writing scripts, but i'm such an SVN newbie I wouldn't know where to begin

Comment: @7579 [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) is just an Explorer shell extension for [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) command line utility (with occasional trickery). Tortoise installer added new folder to `PATH` environment variable. You could open the command prompt and enter `svn help log`, or visit [the help page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html), and go from there :)